# Access a riverpod provider from within another riverpod provider

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, riverpod

I am in the process of converting providers to riverpod providers. In the provider ChangeNotifier class I have a function that saves the data to a firebase db but I don't know how to access this function in the widget. I have tried ref.watch(UserProvider.saveUser) but I get an error message, Instance member 'saveUser' can't be accessed using static access.

I have looked for an answer to this but I have not found one.

Also, I need to access another provider to pass some data to the saveUser method but I have not found an answer to this either.

Here is the UserProvider:

```
class UserProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  UserProvider._();

  final firestoreService = FirestoreService();
  final companyRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(('Company'));
  final userRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(('users'));

  static final fName = StateProvider<String?>((ref) => '');
  static final lName = StateProvider<String?>((ref) => '');
  static final address1 = StateProvider<String?>((ref) => '');
  static final address2 = StateProvider<String?>((ref) => '');
  static final city = StateProvider<String?>((ref) => '');
  static final state = StateProvider<String?>((ref) => '');
  static final zipCode = StateProvider<String?>((ref) => '');
  static final cellPhone = StateProvider<String?>((ref) => '');
  static final officePhone = StateProvider<String?>((ref) => '');
  static final company = StateProvider<String?>((ref) => '');
  static final mls = StateProvider<String?>((ref) => '');

  saveUser() async {

    if (globals.newUser == true) {
      final DocumentSnapshot currentCompanyProfile =
      await CompanyRef.doc(globals.CompanyId).get();

      var newUser = Users(
          userId: globals.currentuserId,
          fName: _fName,
          lName: _lName,
          mls: _mls,
          mlsId: globals.mlsId,
          address1: currentCompanyProfile.get('address1'),
          address2: currentCompanyProfile.get('address2'),
          city: currentCompanyProfile.get('city'),
          state: currentCompanyProfile.get('state'),
          zipcode: currentCompanyProfile.get('zipCode'),
          cellPhone: currentCompanyProfile.get('cellPhone'),
          officePhone: currentCompanyProfile.get('officePhone'),
          companyId: globals.CompanyId,
          company: _company);
      firestoreService.saveUser(newUser);
      globals.newuser = false;
    } else {
      final DocumentSnapshot currentuserProfile =
        await userRef.doc(globals.currentuserId).get();

      var newUser = Users(
          userId: globals.currentUid,
          fName:
              (fName != null && fName != "") ? fName : currentuserProfile.get('fName'),
          lName:
              (lName != null && lName != "") ? lName : currentuserProfile.get('lName'),
          address1: (address1 != null && address1 != "")
              ? address1
              : currentuserProfile.get('address1'),
          address2: (address2 != null && address2 != "")
              ? address2
              : currentuserProfile.get('address2'),
          city: (city != null && city != "") ? city : currentuserProfile.get('city'),
          state:  (state != null && state != "") ? state : currentuserProfile.get('state'),
          /*state: (globals.selectedState != null)
              ? globals.selectedState
              : globals.currentuserState,*/
          zipcode: (zipCode != null && zipCode != "")
              ? zipCode
              : currentuserProfile.get('zipCode'),
          cellPhone: (cellPhone != null && cellPhone != "")
              ? cellPhone
              : currentuserProfile.get('cellPhone'),
          officePhone: (officePhone != null && officePhone != "")
              ? officePhone
              : currentuserProfile.get('officePhone'),
          companyId: globals.CompanyId,
          company: (company != null && company != "")
              ? company
              : currentuserProfile.get('Company'),
          mlsId: globals.mlsId,
          mls: (mls != null && mls != "")
              ? mls
              : currentuserProfile.get('mls'));
      firestoreService.saveUser(newUser);
    }
  }

  deleteuser(String? userId) {
    firestoreService.deleteUser(userId);
  }
}
```

I have created a GlobalsProvider class to replace the global variables I was using so I want to use these new providers to replace the globals variables I am still using in this UserProvider class. How do I do that?

Finally, in my ConsumerState widget I want to access the saveUser() method in the UserProvider class. Here is where I am trying to do that:

```
 RoundedButton(
              title: 'Save',
              colour: Colors.blueAccent,
              onPressed: () async {
                setState(() {
                  showSpinner = true;
                });
                try {
                  agentProvider.saveUser();  <<<< NEED TO ACCESS saveUser()
                  ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUserName.notifier).state = fNameController.value.text +
                      ' ' +
                      lNameController.value.text;
                  ref.read(GlobalsProvider.currentUserState.notifier).state = _currentUserState;
                  await _firestoreService.saveDeviceToken();
                  ref.read(GlobalsProvider.targetScreen.notifier).state = 0;
                  Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => MainScreen()));
                  setState(() {
                    showSpinner = false;
                  });
                } catch (e) {
                  // todo: add better error handling
                  print(e);
                }
              },
```

I have 3 more providers to convert so I am sure there will be many more questions.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please stop using StateProvider.  It's legacy, not intended for use in new applications, although still fully supported. The literature is rushing to catch up with Remi's prolific development.  In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).